# top navigation bar becomes visible when navigation back from push segue on iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode5

I'm hiding the navigationbar on a certain view, and when the user presses a button on the view, i'm *pushing* it to the next view. 
In the next view, I am not longer hiding the nav bar and as expected it becomes visible. When hitting back however, the navbar on the first view also becomes (somehow) visible.

I'm hiding the top navbar like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

And I'm making it visible like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

I wonder what could be wrong with this, as it's quite basic but somehow has a glitch.

Answer (score 1):

In Parent VC's `viewWillAppear` method hide the navigation bar.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}
```